# Process.Start() to run command in the command prompt is not working on the server

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code to run a command in the command prompt to generate a file.

```
var ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
ps.FileName = "cmd.exe";
ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
ps.Arguments = $"/k lighthouse {url} --output json --output-path {outputPath}\\{fileName} --only-categories=pwa, performance";
Process.Start(ps);
```

This works on my local windows computer, howerver, on the windows server nohting happens. When the command runs correctly it should create a JSON file. Does anyone have any idea why it could be not workig on the server? It doesn't throw an error, so I'm having a tough time debugging this.

I have done research and tried changting the properties of the Process class, howerver, nothing changed it. Also, when I run the command manually on the server it works.

Comment: Have you try to excute the same cmmand in the windows server ？We need to make sure it works well first.

Comment: Yes, I have run it manually and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue related to permission. You know the command will run in the server, that means all the web users could run it, it has risk. So it's not recommand way to implement this.

Why you can run it in local, usually we have enough permission to do anything, that why we can invoke it in our personal computer.

**How to fix it**

We can try to use `System.CommandLine` to replace using `ProcessStartInfo`  in the code.

[System.CommandLine overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/)